# How can I completely remove rEFInd from my Mac?

Tags: mac, multi-boot, uninstall

I installed rEFInd to have Ubuntu on an external drive, but no luck. Now I have decided to completely remove rEFInd from my Macbook Pro.

I removed the folder `/efi/`, but the boot manager keeps appearing. How can I completely remove rEFInd from my Mac?

Answer (score 16):

```
diskutil list | grep EFI | awk '{print $6}'
```

This will only output the lines of containing the string "efi" and of that line, only the 6th column, so the output is likely:

```
disk0s1
```

Now to remove refind:

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/efi
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/efi
sudo rm -rfP /Volumes/efi/EFI/refind
sudo bless --setBoot --mount /
```

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue and I managed to solve it by reinstalling rEFInd (using the standard installation), rebooting, and then running

```
$ sudo rm -r /EFI/refind
```

to uninstall, as suggested on http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#uninstalling.

Now Macbook reboots straight into OS X (Mavericks). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If Using rEFInd 0.8.4 or later use the following commands to remove completely,
as it gets installed on the hidden EFI Partition:

```
[[ -d /efi/refind ]] && sudo rm -R -f /efi/refind
[[ -d /EFI/refind ]] && sudo rm -R -f /EFI/refind
efivol=$(diskutil list | grep " EFI " | grep -o 'disk.*' | head -n 1)
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/${efivol} /Volumes/ESP
[[ $? != 0 ]] && sudo mount -t hfs /dev/${efivol} /Volumes/ESP
[[ -d /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind ]] && sudo rm -R -f /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind
sudo umount /Volumes/ESP
sudo bless --setBoot --mount /
```